# How to compute a Ruby division between integers in variables?

Tags: ruby

I have to integer variables `a` and `b`.

I would like to compute the percentage `a/b` in ruby, considering that if both are zero the result should be zero.

With literals its easy, I just need to add `.0` in the numbers: `12.0/17.0`, with variables that come from other calculations:

```
# a == 12 and b == 17    
  a/b => 0

# a == 0 and b == 0    
  a/b => Infinity
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `a.to_f/b` so you convert the integer number in a floating number.
Another trick you can do is something like `a*1.0/b`, but I think the first solution is better.

Just check the `a==0 && b==0` with an `if`.

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to do it in one statement? (but it's ok if there isn't)

Comment: Something like: `(a==0&&b==0)?0:a.to_f/b` should work. Anyway it's not so different from an extended if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
p = a.to_f / b
p = 0 if (b == 0)
```